# laravel's environment file .env always clean itself during development

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, development-environment

I face an issue when in development, my laravel's environment file : **.env**, usually clean itself whenever I update the client-side code (*.vue files).

I'm using VueJS as client and running the run-time build/watch whenever we have some change, we can refresh the browser to see the change but usually, I don't know why it always clear the laravel .env file to a blank file. It's so annoy.

Fronend command building during the dev:

```
npm run dev
// or
npm run watch

// configure as

cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

Who might face the same issue? Any solution or way to find-out the root cause?

Noted: In production, it's OK. (Laravel 5.8 / VueJS 2.x)

Comment: What's the exact command that you are running to build front-end assets? Are you using NPM, Yarn, ...? Can you post the console output of the command too?

Comment: I run : `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` as in webpack as this way:
`cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`